# Weird caching issue in UITableView (Swift 4)

Tags: ios, swift

I'm having a very odd issue with my app, and all I can think of is that it is some sort of caching issue. Basically, when I scroll my `UITableView`, the thumbnails that are shown are being reloaded multiple times for the same row, typically with different images each time, before finally landing on the right image.

A short (20 second) screen capture is here: https://youtu.be/oa04mlOgMeQ

The app should be caching these once loaded, and the images are named to match the bonus codes (and the name is in the JSON file). I can't figure out why it is doing this.

EDIT: Here is my cellForRowAt code:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cellIdentifier = "BonusListViewCell"
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? BonusListViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of BonusListViewCell.")
        }
        // let bonus = bonuses[indexPath.row]
        let bonus: JsonFile.JsonBonuses
        if isFiltering() {
            bonus = filteredBonuses[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            bonus = bonuses[indexPath.row]
        }

        let urlString = "http://tourofhonor.com/appimages/"+(bonus.imageName)
        let url = URL(string: urlString)
        cell.primaryImage.downloadedFrom(url: url!)
        cell.nameLabel.text = bonus.name.capitalized
        cell.bonusCodeLabel.text = bonus.bonusCode.localizedUppercase
        cell.categoryLabel.text = bonus.category
        cell.valueLabel.text = "\(bonus.value)"
        cell.cityLabel.text = "\(bonus.city.capitalized),"
        cell.stateLabel.text = bonus.state.localizedUppercase

        return cell
    }
```

Here is my `downloadedFrom` function:

```
extension UIImageView {
    func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data)
                else { return }
            DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                self.image = image
            }
            }.resume()
    }
    func downloadedFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

My UITableViewCell code is:

```
import UIKit

class BonusListViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var bonusCodeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var flavorText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var primaryImage: UIImageView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }

}
```

Comment: use SDWebImage or AlamofireImage it will take care for that

Comment: Please edit the question to show your `cellForRowAt` method and the code you are using to load the thumbnails if it isn't in that method.

Comment: @Paulw11 I have added the requested code. The thumbnail fetch is in there as well.

Comment: Can you show the code in `.downloadedFrom(url: url!)` - that is where the image download actually occurs

Comment: @Paulw11 I have added it.

Comment: I would agree that you should look at something like `SDWebImage` to make this easier/more reliable,  but your problem is that the image download takes time and by the time the image is downloaded, the cell has been reused and another download has started and then potentially another as you continue to scroll and the cell is reused again. As these downloads compete the images appear in turn until the final image is downloaded.

Comment: Unfortunately it will be hard for you to fix because you are fetching the image as an extension of the `UIImageView` itself and extensions cannot add stored properties.  You could subclass `UIImageView` so that you could store the URL you are currently fetching in a property, then when the fetch is complete, compare the property against the url you just fetched; if they are different, assume you have fetched an outdated image and don't set the image.  This code doesn't do any caching, which is also significantly impacting performance

Comment: @DJFriar You are not really caching anything, the image will gone when cell got reused, you have to save your image to disk or mem (by another instance) then check the name or url to get that image

Comment: why cant you try this library https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher

Comment: @Tj3n I feel you are right. I think I'll tweak the app to download the sample image on view of the detail page, and then make the UITableView display a default image, unless the sample image is present locally.

Answer (score 0):

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cellIdentifier = "BonusListViewCell"
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? BonusListViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of BonusListViewCell.")
    }
    // let bonus = bonuses[indexPath.row]
    let bonus: JsonFile.JsonBonuses
    if isFiltering() {
        bonus = filteredBonuses[indexPath.row]
    } else {
        bonus = bonuses[indexPath.row]
    }

    let urlString = "http://tourofhonor.com/appimages/"+(bonus.imageName)
    let url = URL(string: urlString)

    //set image url
    cell.imageUrl = URL(string: images[indexPath.row])

    cell.nameLabel.text = bonus.name.capitalized
    cell.bonusCodeLabel.text = bonus.bonusCode.localizedUppercase
    cell.categoryLabel.text = bonus.category
    cell.valueLabel.text = "\(bonus.value)"
    cell.cityLabel.text = "\(bonus.city.capitalized),"
    cell.stateLabel.text = bonus.state.localizedUppercase

    return cell
}
```

> In your cell

```
import UIKit

class BonusListViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var bonusCodeLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var categoryLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var cityLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var stateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var flavorText: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var primaryImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var activity: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    var imageUrl: URL? {
        didSet {
            loadImage()
        }
    }
    var task: URLSessionDataTask?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        clean()
    }

    func loadImage() {

        //you need cancel previous task
        task?.cancel()

        clean()
        guard let imageUrl = imageUrl else {
            return
        }
        activity.startAnimating()
        task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageUrl) { [weak self] data, response, error in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.activity.stopAnimating()
                if error == nil, let data = data {
                    self?.primaryImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
                }
            }
        }
        task?.resume()
    }

    func clean() {
        primaryImage.image = nil
    }
}
```

But it's better to use libraries like **Alamofire** or **SDWebImage**

Answer (score -2):

Your problem is that previously dispatched image fetches are completing after the cell has been reused, resulting in outdated images appearing, in turn, until the final, correct, image is loaded.

There are existing frameworks available that will make this easier for you and also perform caching, but you may not want to introduce 3rd party code into your app.

One approach is to use a `UIImageView` subclass rather than an extension so that you can add a property for the current url and an in-memory cache:

```
class LoadableImageView: UIImageView {

    private var currentURL: URL?
    private static imageCache = NSCache<NSURL,UIImage>()
    private static cacheUpdateQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)

    func downloadedFrom(url: URL, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        contentMode = mode
        self.currentURL = url

        if let image = LoadableImageView.imageCache.object(forKey:url as NSURL) {
            self.image = image
            return
        }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let httpURLResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpURLResponse.statusCode == 200,
                let mimeType = response?.mimeType, mimeType.hasPrefix("image"),
                let data = data, error == nil,
                let image = UIImage(data: data),
                url == self.currentURL
                else { return }
                LoadableImageView.cacheUpdateQueue.sync {
                    LoadableImageView.imageCache.setObject(image, forKey: url as NSURL)
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async() {
                     self.image = image 
                }
            }.resume()
    }
    func downloadedFrom(link: String, contentMode mode: UIViewContentMode = .scaleAspectFit) {
        guard let url = URL(string: link) else { return }
        downloadedFrom(url: url, contentMode: mode)
    }
}
```

You will need to set an appropriate placeholder image or `nil` in `prepareForReuse` or `cellForRowAt`

Comment: You are correct that I would prefer to avoid 3rd party code if possible. In searching my project, I don't have `prepareForReuse` anywhere in the project. I think it should go in my UITableViewCell code, which I have added to my original question. How would I use prepareForReuse to point at my DefaultImage?

Comment: You are correct, `prepareForReuse` can be declared in your cell subclass.  You could put something like `self.imageView.image = nil` or `self.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"placeholder.jpg")` or whatever

Comment: Feel free to tell me I'm barking up the wrong tree, but I wonder if I should use CoreData to store these images. The images in question are samples, that the user will then take their own version of using the app. My thinking was that since they are divided by state, most riders won't look at all 350 images, so I could just load them on demand and retain them. Would it make sense to just save them to CoreData on first load instead of trying to cache or fetch all the time?

Comment: You could do that if they are essentially static.  You could use Core Data or just save the files in the documents directory